# Can I use compiled Svelte as a script that connects to different websites?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I wonder if I can write some Svelte code, compile it to a single .js file, and connect it as a 'widget' to other websites? For example, I will create a floating modal and the modal will appear based on a website domain. The user will just add my script to his DOM.
Is it possible or I better use vanilla js for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can export svelte code as web component
https://blog.logrocket.com/build-web-components-svelte/

Answer (score 0):

Whether to use Svelte or not depends on the complexity; the higher it is, the more you will gain from the abstractions and automatic state synchronization.

Svelte components can be built to plain JS or [web components/custom elements](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-custom-element-api). A regular Svelte component has a [client side constructor](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-client-side-component-api) where the `target` option sets where to add the component, so it can be added anywhere in existing pages.